# Simulate GROUP_CONCAT function in HSQLDB versions < 2?

Tags: sql, hsqldb, group-concat, openoffice-base, libreoffice-base

LO/OOO **Base** doesn't come with an HSQLDB version > 2 which means there is no `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

***Is there a way to simulate this function in HSQLDB versions < 2?***

Here's an example for the columns `name` and `value` before the function is applied:

```
TIM   |  51
TIM   |  53
TIM   |  55
JOHN  |  103
JOHN  |  104
```

I would like to use (H)SQL code in Base that returns something similar to the result of GROUP_CONCAT:

```
TIM   | 51, 53, 55
JOHN  | 103, 104
```

([A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005) has been asked for other DBMS but the answers did't work for me in HSQLDB.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no practical way to do this with HSQLDB 1.8.0.

You can, however, replace the jar that is supplied with LO/OOo with HSQLDB 2.2.9 (release candidate atm) and create and use external HSQLDB databases. Existing databases can also be converted.

See the http://www.ooofoum.org for detailed instructions and helper programs. A short guide is here: http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=17567

Update: The latest HSQLDB 2.2.9 release candidate can be used with LO/OOo. The database embedded in an .odb file is updated to the new version and the file cannot be opened without the latest HSQLDB.